# Python3.6 cocotb coroutine: calling asynchronous function containing ”yield“ in synchronous function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, yield, cocotb

I encountered some problems while trying to make a synchronous function that calls asynchronous functions.(python 3.6.9, cocotb 1.4.0)

As shown in the following example code. The `read_cb` function will call `read` function(in `FakeDriver` class).

After running, I get the error

```
yield self._fake_lock()
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <cocotb.decorators.RunningCoroutine object at 0x7f7fecdbfe10>
```

What I want is

```
init FakerDriver
locking... 
locking done
read...
addr: 0x01 
unlocking... 
unlocking done
read done
```

```py
import cocotb
import asyncio
from cocotb.decorators import coroutine
from cocotb.triggers import Event

class FakeDriver():
    def __init__(self):
        print("init FakeDriver")
        self.busy_event = Event("driver_busy")
        self.busy = False

    @coroutine
    def read(self, addr):
        print("read...")

        yield self._fake_lock()
        print("addr: ", addr)
        self._fake_unlock()

        print("read done")

    @coroutine
    def _fake_lock(self):
        print("locking...")
        if self.busy:
            yield self.busy_event.wait()

        self.busy_event.clear()
        self.busy = True
        print("locking done")

    def _fake_unlock(self):
        print("unlocking...")
        self.busy = False
        self.busy_event.set()
        print("unlocking done")

def read_cb():
    dri = FakeDriver()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(dri.read("0x01"))
    ret = loop.run_until_complete(task)
    loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_cb()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? Are you trying to support an old version of python 3? The @coroutine decorator (of asyncio) is deprecated. And you should use `async def` syntax instead. This will probably true for the cocotb library too. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine If you are trying to use an old version of python, then you should probably be doing `yield from` rather than `yield`.

Comment: The old version of python is 3.4. In 3.5+ you should use `async def` and `await`, and python 3.3 doesn't have asyncio.

Comment: @Dunes Hi, I am using python3.6.9 cocotb 1.4.0. If using `yield from`, there will be a error:  `yield from self._fake_lock()
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'RunningCoroutine'`

Comment: Did you try `yield from` for both coroutines? Also, did you try using stuff like `async def read(self, addr)` (without @coroutine) and `await self._fake_lock()`? Again, you'll need to do that for both functions.

Comment: @Dunes, As you said. It works. Thank you so much for you advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix up cocotb's own implementation of coroutines with asyncio's.
In your case, get rid of the `asyncio` import completely and, with your oldish cocotb 1.4.0, use cocotb's `fork()` instead of `create_task()` (as described in https://docs.cocotb.org/en/v1.4.0/quickstart.html?highlight=fork#parallel-and-sequential-execution).

Before you create lots of new code using the deprecated `yield` etc. in cocotb, consider upgrading cocotb to 1.6.1 and use `async def`/`await` (again from `cocotb`, not `asyncio`), and instead of `fork()`, use `start_soon()` (see https://docs.cocotb.org/en/v1.6.1/coroutines.html#concurrent-execution and https://www.fossi-foundation.org/2021/10/20/cocotb-1-6-0).

(I now see you also asked this in https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/issues/2819)

Comment: I'm not writing code from scratch. This project already has a lot of code. Due to historical reasons, I can't upgrade cocotb yet. In the above code, if I change `read_cb` function to`def read_cb(): dri = FakeDriver()  ret = cocotb.fork(dri.read("0x22"))`  there will be an error: `File "fake_driver.py", line 66, in read_cb
    ret = cocotb.fork(dri.read("0x22"))
  File "/home/pengfei/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cocotb/__init__.py", line 135, in fork
    return scheduler.add(coro)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`  Do you have any advice?

Comment: The only way `scheduler` could be `None` is if you are not running an HDL simulator. cocotb *only* runs within an HDL simulator.

Comment: @ktb Thank you for your guidance. You're absolutely right. Since this is my first time using cocotb, I don't know this:-）

Comment: @ktb Another question, if `read_cb` function is `def read_cb(): dri = FakeDriver()  ret = cocotb.fork(dri.read("0x22"))`. How can I get the return value of the `dri.read("0x22")` function? The type of `ret` is `RunningCoroutine`, not a return value from `dri.read("0x22")`.

Comment: `fork` runs `read` concurrently and independently, allowing the function calling `fork` to continue running. You must `yield dri.read("0x22")` if you want to wait until `read` finishes running, *or* you can `yield task` some time later.

Comment: But the `read_cb` function is not a coroutine.(it's a callback function from C code). It seems that I can not use `yield` or `await` in `read_cb` function. Is there any way to get the return value of `dri.read("0x22")` in `read_cb` ?

Comment: Everything in the `read_cb` function you posted is incorrect. If you want to run a cocotb test in a simulator you will have to create a `@cocotb.test()` coroutine function, where you create your driver and do `yield dri.read()`. Please have a look at the examples in the repo.

Comment: In my case, I need to make a library(a wrapper of C code) instead of a cocotb test. The library will be used by cocotb tests. The functions in this library are ordinary Python functions, not coroutine. Functions in this library need to call the read/write operations in the driver in a blocking way. The driver read/write are implemented based on cocotb. I need this library to interact with this driver. Do you have any suggestions? I can think of the worst solution is to use socket. Is there a better way?